# How is it possible to stop a debounced Rxjs Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I created an observable, which will fire 3 seconds after the last change is made, and calls the `publishChange` of the service. It works, but I would like to create a `doImmediateChange` function, which calls `publishChange` immediately and stops the debounced observable. How is that possible?

My component:

```
class MyComponent {
    private updateSubject = new Subject<string>();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.updateSubject.pipe(
            debounceTime(3000),
            distinctUntilChanged()
        ).subscribe(val => {
            this.srv.publishChange(val);
        });
    }

    doChange(val: string) {
        this.updateSubject.next(val);
    }

    doImmediateChange(val: string) {

        // Stop the current updateSubject if debounce is in progress and call publish immediately
        // ??
        this.srv.publishChange(val);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [race operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/race):

The first observable to complete becomes the **only** observable subscribed to, so this recursive function will complete after one emission `take(1)`, then resubscribe `() => this.raceRecursive()`.

```
private timed$ = new Subject<string>();
private event$ = new Subject<string>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.raceRecursive()
}

raceRecursive() {
  race(
    this.timed$.pipe(debounceTime(1000)),
    this.event$
  )
    .pipe(take(1)) // force it to complete
    .subscribe(
      val => console.log(val), // srv call here
      err => console.error(err),
      () => this.raceRecursive() // reset it once complete
    )
}

doChange(val: string) {
  this.timed$.next(val)
}

doImmediateChange(val: string) {
  this.event$.next(val)
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can emulate `debounceTime` using `switchMap` and `delay`. Then cancel the inner Observable with `takeUntil` to prevent a waiting value from being emitted.

```js
private updateSubject = new Subject<string>();
private interrupt = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.updateSubject.pipe(
    switchMap(val => of(val).pipe(
      delay(3000),
      takeUntil(this.interrupt)
    ))
  ).subscribe(val => publish(val));
}

doChange(val: string) {
  this.updateSubject.next(val);
}

doImmediateChange(val: string) {
  this.interrupt.next();
  publish(val);
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ya93fb

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this behavior using [debounce](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debounce.html) and [race](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/race.html):
with the code you provided

```js
private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
private immediate$ = new Subject<void>();
private updateSubject$ = new Subject<string>();

constructor(private srv: PubSubService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.updateSubject$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      debounce(() => race(timer(3000), this.immediate$))
  ).subscribe(val => {
      this.srv.publishChange(val);
  });
}

doChange(val: string, immediate?: boolean) {
  this.updateSubject$.next(val);
  if (immediate) this.immediate$.next();
}

// don't forget to unsubscribe
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
}
```

emitting an immediate change will replace the previous normal change (that is debounced for 3s) without the delay (thanks to our race observable).

here's a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndzayw)

Comment: This approach has the problem that your final Observable will emit the previous value if your source Observable emits its values asynchronously. e.g. if you replace your source Observable `this.updateSubject$` with `this.updateSubject$.pipe(switchMap(v => Promise.resolve(v)))` and do a normal change before you do an immediate change you will see that the value from the normal change will be emitted when instead the immediate value should be emitted. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iugnvu

Comment: You’re right but The OP hasn’t said anything about async data. Your use case is irrelevant to the question and of course will need a different implementation to overcome this

Comment: Maybe, but it's always best to write code or operators that work for any source Observable not just for some specific ones, as people might want to use your solution in different cases than the one from the question. I also first tried to come up with a solution using `debounce` but ran into the same problem you did and couldn't come up with one working in all cases. Other than that it's a nice approach.

Comment: I kinda don't agree with you, there will never be an 'all-in-one' solution for observables and streams as any stream has a different purpose, I think that the solution to your case is to separate the streams: 1 stream that only handles publishing updates and another stream to handle async updates before publishing them:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpwpmn
let me know what you think

Comment: But having a function that executes asynchronously in your pipe or somehow delays  a value to emit is quiet common. If you can come up with a solution that'll be nice :)

Comment: @fridoo did you saw the stackblitz i've provided?

Answer (score 1):

You could supply a value specific debounce time with every value and use `debounce` with `timer` to change the debounce time for values dynamically.

```ts
private updateSubject = new Subject<{ value: any, debounceTime: number}>();

ngOnInit() {
  updateSubject.pipe(
    debounce(({ debounceTime }) => timer(debounceTime)),
    pluck('value')
  ).subscribe(val => publish(val));
}

doChange(value: string) {
  updateSubject.next({ value, debounceTime: 3000 });
}

doImmediateChange(value: string) {
  updateSubject.next({ value, debounceTime: 0 });
}
```

This doesn't directly stop the debounced Observable but let's you "overwrite" a waiting value with a new one being emitted with zero delay.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-j15zyq

(user733421 didn't seem to want to add a complete solution so I expanded the approach)

Answer (score 0):

The value for debounceTime is only evaluated once, on observable creation time.

To be able to dynamically update debounceTime, use debounce together with timer, like this :

```
 debounce(()=>timer(this.debounceTime)),
```

Comment: You should add an example of how this can be used to solve the problem.